# How to search in a column of a dataframe for any and all value in a column another dataframe in Python using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, excel, dataframe

I have an excel file in which one of the columns contain IDs. Some cells have one ID but other has 2 or more separated by `;`(Main dataframe)

I have another dataframe which has list of IDs of first type
I have a third dataframe which has a list of IDs of second type.

I want to create a new column in the main dataframe saying if any of the IDs belong to first type.
When there are multiple IDs in the cell, if at least one of them belong to first data type it should classify it as first. If none of the IDs belong to first, but all of them belong to second it should classify it as second. If it does not belong in any it should classify as NA.

For example:

Main Dataframe

| name. | ID. |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1234; 5678 |
| b. | 9abc. |
| c. | 9def ;9ghj |
| d. | 1234; 9ghj |
| e. | xyzd. |

First type

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| x | 1234 |
| y | 9def |

Second type

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| x | 5678 |
| y | 9abc |

I want it to say a is first type, b is second type, c is first type, d is first type, e is NA

I tried using `df.contains`

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df_data = {
    'name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    'ID': ['1234;5678', '9abc.', '9def;9ghj', '1234;9ghj', 'xyzd.']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(df_data)
print("df:")
print(df)
df1_data = {'type1': ['x', 'y'],'ID': ['1234', '9def']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1_data)
print("\ndf1:")
print(df1)
df2_data = {'type2': ['x', 'y'],'ID': ['5678', '9abc']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2_data)
print("\ndf2:")
print(df2)
df['type'] = np.NaN
for dft in [df1, df2]:
    for id in dft['ID']:
        mask = df['ID'].str.contains(id) & df['type'].isna()
        df.loc[mask, 'type'] = dft.columns[0]
print("-" * 10)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
df:                                                                        
  name         ID                                                          
0    a  1234;5678                                                          
1    b      9abc.                                                          
2    c  9def;9ghj                                                          
3    d  1234;9ghj                                                          
4    e      xyzd.                                                          
                                                                           
df1:                                                                       
  type1    ID                                                              
0     x  1234                                                              
1     y  9def                                                              
                                                                           
df2:                                                                       
  type2    ID                                                              
0     x  5678                                                              
1     y  9abc                                                              
----------                                                                 
  name         ID   type                                                   
0    a  1234;5678  type1                                                   
1    b      9abc.  type2                                                   
2    c  9def;9ghj  type1                                                   
3    d  1234;9ghj  type1                                                   
4    e      xyzd.    NaN
```