# Extract strings from dataframe object column with .split() and .strip()

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, membership

I have a dataframe `'merged_tstbr'` with over 17000 rows and a column `'ID'`. In this column multiple entries appear as one long string, separated by `';'` and `\n`.

Here an example of what a cell in this column looks like:

```
XDX_AbCd_XY_2415;\
XDX_AbCd_XY_3335;\
XDX_AbCd_XY_3351;\
XDX_AbCd_XY_3354
```

I have used the below script to check for all rows in 'ID' column and add to a new list 'tstbr_anf' if the ID is in my_list:

```
my_list = ['XDX_AbCd_XY_3351', 'XDX_AbCd_XY_3335'] # (and so on, 250 elements in total)
```

```
for index, row in merged_tstbr.iterrows():
    row_values = [value.strip() for value in row['ID'].split('\n')]       
    matching = [value for value in row_values if value in my_list]
    tstbr_anf.extend(matching)
```

Out of 250 elements, 6 are not showing in `txtbr_anf`.

I checked the presence of these in the column 'ID' in excel, and they are here, but somehow not getting added to `txtbr_anf`. They are present in my_list as well.

What can be the possible reasons for this.

Follow-up from [How to search in a column of a dataframe for any and all value in a column another dataframe in Python using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77098190/12846804)

Comment: You don't strip the `;`?

Comment: Can you provide a DataFrame constructor for an example? Also, how many items do you have in `my_list`?

Comment: @mozway I have 250 items in my_list. I have the merged_tstbr from another function and have filtered for crtain values in other columns

Comment: @OCa Yes. And from domain knowledge, I know for this all the elements should match the list. I checked the presence of the missing IDs in the column 'ID' in excel [the excel which I converted to dataframe merged) and they are here but somehow not getting added to the tstbr_anf. They are present in my_list as well.

Comment: @Maze a [MRE](/q/20109391/16343464) as code would be appreciated

Comment: @MatthiasHuschle I tried splitting wrt ';' but then \n character still stays and the IDs are not seperated properly.

Comment: If you provide the 6 elements that are not showing it would be helpful for debugging, in addition to a minimal reproducible code example.

Comment: any feedback regarding the provided solutions?

Answer (score 1):

**Input data I've used to try and reproduce your issue**

- It is based on the content of a cell that you posted,
- I have added a second row with simply modified digits.

```py
my_list = ['XDX_AbCd_XY_3351', 'XDX_AbCd_XY_3335']

merged_tstbr = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['XDX_AbCd_XY_2415;\nXDX_AbCd_XY_3335;\nXDX_AbCd_XY_3351;\nXDX_AbCd_XY_3354',
                                    'XDX_AbCd_XY_1234;\nXDX_AbCd_XY_4565;\nXDX_AbCd_XY_3579;\nXDX_AbCd_XY_7592']})
```

Each cell in your input dataframe contains a number of *IDs* together in a string:

```py
                                                  ID
0  XDX_AbCd_XY_2415;\nXDX_AbCd_XY_3335;\nXDX_AbCd...
1  XDX_AbCd_XY_1234;\nXDX_AbCd_XY_4565;\nXDX_AbCd...
```

**Please confirm this matches your input**, otherwise provide a dataframe constructor.

---

**Problem:**

You seem to believe that `.strip()` removes semicolons, but it does not, unless you force it to. You could verify that with a `print` (commented out in the code below): the `row_values` you were testing membership for, **still have their semicolon** about them:

```
['XDX_AbCd_XY_2415;', 'XDX_AbCd_XY_3335;', 'XDX_AbCd_XY_3351;', 'XDX_AbCd_XY_3354']
```

---

**Quick fix:**

1. Either add it in the `.split()`, then `.strip()` is not needed:

```py
for index, row in merged_tstbr.iterrows():
    row_values = [value for value in row['ID'].split(';\n')]       
    #print(row_values)
    matching = [value for value in row_values if value in my_list]
    tstbr_anf.extend(matching)
```

2. Or force the `.strip()` to care:

```
    row_values = [value.strip(';') for value in row['ID'].split('\n')]
```

Both will output `tstbr_anf` as:

```
['XDX_AbCd_XY_3335', 'XDX_AbCd_XY_3351']
```

Now why this problem only arises with 6 IDs, we can only know when you provide larger input data. It could be that semicolons are present in only few cells.

If your data looks anything like in your previous question [How to search in a column of a dataframe for any and all value in a column another dataframe in Python using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77098190/12846804), then indeed not all IDs have semicolons but it could also be other undesired characters.

---

**Alternative suggestion**

The two-step process below will extract those IDs and retain, in a list, those only present in *my_list*. You can then directly assign to `tstbr_anf`.

1. Clean up IDs

   - generates a list of lists, one sublist by cell from that dataframe column)
   - acounts for semicolons possibly not being present in all cases

```py
L = merged_tstbr['ID'].str.split(pat = ';\n|\n', regex=True)

0    [XDX_AbCd_XY_2415, XDX_AbCd_XY_3335, XDX_AbCd_...
1    [XDX_AbCd_XY_1234, XDX_AbCd_XY_4565, XDX_AbCd_...
```

2. Next step does two things at once:

   - flatten the "list of sublists" into a simple list
   - and filter according to my_list

```py
my_set = set(my_list) # sets allow faster membership search

tstbr_anf = [item 
             for sublist in L
             for item in sublist 
             if item in my_set]
```

Final output:

```
['XDX_AbCd_XY_3335', 'XDX_AbCd_XY_3351']
```

As you can see, we've gotten rid of the intermediate `matching` list, which was the temporary product of each row iteration in your code.

References

- Double comprehension: [How do I make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/12846804)
- Membership test performance: [Python Sets vs Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2831212/12846804)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to find the global intersection of your list and **all** items in the Series, I would use a `set` intersection and a regex split:

```
my_list = ['XDX_AbCd_XY_3351', 'XDX_AbCd_XY_3335']
my_set = set(my_list)

out = my_set.intersection(merged_tstbr['ID'].str.split('[;\n]+').explode())

# or
out = my_set.intersection(set().union(*merged_tstbr['ID'].str.split('[;\n]+')))
```

Example output: `{'XDX_AbCd_XY_3335', 'XDX_AbCd_XY_3351'}`

If you want the intersection **per row**:

```
import re

my_set = set(my_list)
out = [my_set.intersection(re.split('[;\n]+', s)) for s in merged_tstbr['ID']]
```

For a new column:

```
merged_tstbr['new'] = [my_set.intersection(re.split('[;\n]+', s))
                       for s in merged_tstbr['ID']]
```

Example output:

```
                                                                          ID                                   new
0  XDX_AbCd_XY_2415;\nXDX_AbCd_XY_3335;\nXDX_AbCd_XY_3351;\nXDX_AbCd_XY_3354  {XDX_AbCd_XY_3335, XDX_AbCd_XY_3351}
1                     XDX_AbCd_XY_2416;\nXDX_AbCd_XY_3336;\nXDX_AbCd_XY_3351                    {XDX_AbCd_XY_3351}
```

Used input:

```
merged_tstbr = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['XDX_AbCd_XY_2415;\nXDX_AbCd_XY_3335;\nXDX_AbCd_XY_3351;\nXDX_AbCd_XY_3354',
                                    'XDX_AbCd_XY_2416;\nXDX_AbCd_XY_3336;\nXDX_AbCd_XY_3351']})
```

Comment: Having an attribute error saying : 'str' object has no attribute 'intersection'

Comment: @Maze `S = set(my_list)` so `S` cannot be a `str`, please check again you've not used my exact code.

Comment: Pasting my code below

Comment: s = set(self.bsm_rel_list)
            out = [s.intersection(re.split('[;\n]+', s)) for s in merged_tstbr['RQID']]
            for index, row in merged_tstbr_nr.iterrows():
            print('Anzahl Testbarer Anforderungen', len(set(out)))

Comment: You reuse `s`/`s` where I have `S`/`s` (note the different case!) I changed the variable name to `my_set` for clarity.

Comment: Also I don't see why you use `iterrows`, if you want a set **per row** you have to assign or `zip` the values

Comment: This might be a quite stupid. But I would like to remove the duplicates from the 'out' and print how many items it has. I used "len(list(set(out)))". But I amm getting error saying unhashable type: 'set'

Comment: @Maze can you provide the explicit expected output as edit to your question for clarity?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255572/discussion-between-maze-and-mozway).